# Python синтез речи на линукс

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-to-speech

Как можно сделать на питоне синтез речи с нормальным синтезатором. Пробовал я gtts, но он не подошел(он только с поключением к интернету работает) Так же пробовал pyttsx, он идеален, но синтезатор голоса который он потребовал к установки, очень корявый и непонятно, что он произносит.

Comment: Лучший синтезатор конечно silero бесплатный, рабочий очень приятный голос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуй Festival, стандартный голос может противный, но говорит четко.

Этот патч поможет от `undefined symbol: ...`

```
pip3 install --upgrade --user https://github.com/alex-eri/pyfestival/archive/patch-1.zip#festival
```

python3

```
import festival
festival.sayText('hello')
```

Если звук не воспроизводится попробуй:

```
import festival
festival.textToWavFile('hello')
```

Эта функция сохраняет файл с уже готовым текстом. Также она возвращает путь к файлу строкой.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87331/discussion-on-answer-by-eri-python----).

Comment: @PashaPash в чат никто не смотрит

Comment: Почему оно на русском не работает?

Comment: Потому что русский голос не установлен