# как на Pyttsx3 синтезировать русский текст в речь(тоже на русском)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, синтезатор-речи, pyttsx3

Наткнулся на видео(на 2:40) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YeS755SPSI8 и решил повторить, но не вышло. в интернете наткнулся на такое решение:

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
ru_voice_id = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\TTS_MS_RU-RU_IRINA_11.0"
engine.setProperty('voice', ru_voice_id)
engine.say('привет')

engine.runAndWait()
```

Но и оно не работает, а вроде всё сделано верно. Как мне в итоге с помощью Pyttsx3 преобразовать текст на русском языке в речь, или есть другие библиотеки, предназначенные для этого?

Comment: Я для синтеза русской речи на python использовал pyfestival. У меня были некоторые проблемы с оберткой, но один человек мне помог <https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/922553/python-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%81>

Для использования русского языка требуется festfox-ru

Comment: не получается установить. Выдает ошибку при установке

Comment: У Вас есть вычислительные мощности? Какая Вам производительность нужна?

Comment: У меня такая же проблема была. Причина в том, что на винде по стандарту стоит 1 голос Анны (можно посмотреть это в: Панель управления - Распознавание речи - Преобразование текста в речь - Выбор голоса), а она только на английском говорит. Поэтому нужно установить синтез русской речи. Сделал как в этом видео, все получилось https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eh2TA--ZDek.

Answer (score 1):

Вот тут посмотрите примеры: [Как сделать говорящую программу на Python самостоятельно?](https://geekbrains.ru/posts/tts_python)

В Windows голос удобно выбирать как по ID, так и по имени. В Linux проще работать с именем или языком голоса. Новый файл set_voice_and_say.py:

```
import pyttsx3

tts = pyttsx3.init()

voices = tts.getProperty('voices')

# Задать голос по умолчанию
tts.setProperty('voice', 'ru') 

# Попробовать установить предпочтительный голос
for voice in voices:
    if voice.name == 'Aleksandr':
        tts.setProperty('voice', voice.id)

tts.say('Командный голос вырабатываю, товарищ генерал-полковник!')
tts.runAndWait()
```

Answer (score 0):

Голос стоит по умолчанию, чего нельзя сказать о громкости речи и о скорости воспроизведения, вам достаточно прописать

```
tts.setProperty("rate", 150)
tts.setProperty("volume", 1)
```