# Не запускается голосовой ассистент

Tags: python, python-3.8, pyttsx3

```
import pyttsx3
engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.say("Привет")
engine.runAndWait()
```

pywin32 227, pypiwin32 223, pyttsx3 2.87 - установлено

Comment: Привет, будет очень хорошо если ты скинешь ещё к коду то что выводит питон. А то очень сложно делать какие-то либо выводы если не знаешь что питон скажет на это.

Comment: он не понимает русский - я тупо лох

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1049688/234134