# pyttsx3 не говорит начало строки

Tags: python, pyttsx3

```
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()

def speaker(text):
    '''Озвучка текста'''
    engine.say(text)
    engine.runAndWait()

speaker("hello hello hello")
```

По каким-то непонятным причинам слышно только "hello hello", а на русском вообще беда.
Как будто в начале сэмпла стоит небольшое приглушение озвучки, а как убрать не знаю(

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/996811/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-pyttsx3-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC - тут про всё есть

Comment: не помогло, я и голоса менял уже штуки 3 попробовал

Comment: Я пример набрал - всё говорит, скорость и громкость меняется

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример:

```
import pyttsx3

tts = pyttsx3.init()    
voices = tts.getProperty('voices')

# Задать голос по умолчанию
tts.setProperty('voice', 'ru') 

# Попробовать установить предпочтительный голос
for voice in voices:
    print(voice)
    if voice.name == 'Aleksandr':
        tts.setProperty('voice', voice.id)

tts.setProperty("rate", 150)
tts.setProperty("volume", 1)

tts.say('Командный голос вырабатываю, товарищ генерал-полковник!')
tts.runAndWait()
```

У меня другие голоса не установлены, поэтому берётся по умолчанию

Comment: Блин , ну почему у меня по-другому. Почему-то говорит только "голос вырабатываю, товарищ генерал-полковник!"

Comment: Обновите pyttsx3. Удалите его, а потом поствьте снова (хотя....)